# Struts2 action works with backslash but not without it

Tags: java, struts2, action, jsp-tags

Inside my form.jsp I am using the following tags below. My action won't work unless I have the / slash in front of Login. I think that is wrong, no examples I've seen use that. Can anybody tell me why I need that and why it doesn't work without it?

```
<s:form action="/Login" >
            <s:textfield name="userName" cssClass="inputStyle" label="User Name" />
            <s:password name="password" cssClass="inputStyle" label="Password" />
            <s:submit method="execute" value="Login" />
        </s:form>
```

Comment: Can you post the the absolute path for both the form.jsp and Login?

Comment: You are making the namespace explicit. You could remove the "/" but you would need to add the namespace="/" attribute/value to the tag. "Login" alone could work but the action would need to be in the default package (namespace is "" generally this is best avoided, people start complaining that they end up with weird URLS when too many actions are done that way)

Comment: Show your `struts.xml` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to Remove package namespace in struts.xml file:
from:

```
 <package name="default" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">
```

to:

```
<package name="default" extends="struts-default">
```

In web.xml file url pattern should be:

```
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
```